# Why does an ERC721 contract need to conform to the ERC721 and ERC165 standard?

Tags: tokens, erc-721

Reading through the EIP for [ERC 721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md#specification) I notice that it is required to implement 2 different interfaces. Why is this?

I noticed this portion in the documentation, but I think some clarification is necessary.

> ERC-165 Interface
>
> We chose Standard Interface Detection (ERC-165) to expose the
>   interfaces that a ERC-721 smart contract supports.
>
> A future EIP may create a global registry of interfaces for contracts.
>   We strongly support such an EIP and it would allow your ERC-721
>   implementation to implement ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Metadata, or other
>   interfaces by delegating to a separate contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ERC-165 standard provides a standard for generating an identifier for an interface.

This way, if the identifier of a *given version of a given interface* matches with your contract, it's a way of ensuring that your contract is compliant with that interface.

As per [line 4 of the specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md),

```
///  Note: the ERC-165 identifier for this interface is 0x80ac58cd
```

Edit:

In plain English, basically it's a way of taking a finger print of the interface, and checking that against a finger print of the functions you've implemented, and makes sure they're the same.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this ERC-165 identifier (0x80ac58cd) makes sure we implement all standard ERC721 functions or is there more to this?